# How to populate a collection inside a DAO object using MyBatis annotaions (or even without it)?

Tags: sql, orm, ibatis, mybatis

I have a DAO `User` :

```
class User{
  int id,
  int name,
  List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}
```

In my `UserMapper.java` interface, I have a method that gives me User DAO :

```
@Select("select u.id, u.name, v.id, v.name from User u, Vehicle v where u.id=#{id} and v.user_id=u.id")
public User getUser(int id);
```

How to make sure that the above query fills the User object's vehicle collection properly ?
**Please use annotations** (and XML only as a last resort)

Answer (score 0):

From [Mybatis 3 User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf),

> Note: You will notice that join mapping is not supported via the Annotations
>   API. This is due to the limitation in Java Annotations that does not
>   allow for circular references.

Best you can do is something like this,

```
@Results({
    @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true),
    @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
    @Result(many=@Many(select="your select"), javaType=Vehicle.class)
})
```

@Select("select u.id, u.name, v.id, v.name from User u, Vehicle v where u.id=#{id} and v.user_id=u.id")
    public User getUser(int id);

My advice,  use the xml.